# Add web hook for inbox emails to company gmail account

Tags: ruby, gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

How can I integrate email inbox from company account to my application? Gems like `mail_room` or `gmail` can connect to one mailbox given that you specify them.

I'm thinking about a web hook like a notification api, but I can't figure out how it works.

How can I add a web hook for inbox emails in company's gmail account? When a message is received in `user@company.com` or `support@company.com` I need to have a notification sent.

Comment: You can also ask gmail server about receive emails. You can set cron to do it e.g.every 5 minutes. I can share you code concept it you are interested in.

Comment: @PiotrGalas I have established a connection with my personal email, but with the corporate email can't do. If you know how to do this, then please tell

Comment: If it is gmail then probably you need to set less restricted mode.

Comment: yes it is gmail, but our company policy is 2 factor authentication, also i don't know how check all emails in our domain

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) for Gmail API.

> **1.Initial Cloud Pub/Sub Setup**
>
> The Gmail API uses the [Cloud Pub/Sub API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) to deliver push
>   notifications. This allows notification via a variety of methods
>   including **webhooks** and polling on a single subscription endpoint.
>
> *Prerequisites*
>
> In order to complete the rest of this setup, make sure you fulfill the
>   Cloud Pub/Sub Prerequisites and then set up a Cloud Pub/Sub client.
>
> *Create a topic*
>
> Using your Cloud Pub/Sub client, create the topic that the Gmail API
>   should send notifications to. The topic name can be any name you
>   choose under your project (i.e. matching projects/myproject/topics/*,
>   where myproject is the Project ID listed for your project in the
>   Google Developers Console).
>
> We recommend that you use a single topic for all Gmail API push
>   notifications for your application, due to Cloud Pub/Sub limits on the
>   number of topics.
>
> *Create a subscription*
>
> Follow the Cloud Pub/Sub Subscriber Guide to set up a subscription to
>   the topic that you created. Configure the subscription type to be
>   either a **webhook** push (i.e. HTTP POST callback) or pull (i.e.
>   initiated by your app). This is how your application will receive
>   notifications for updates.

more on the guide for additional info.